# Remove non-conjugates from complex numbers list

Tags: python-3.x, list, complex-numbers

I have two lists, one contains the real part of imaginary numbers, the other contains the imaginary part of the same numbers. I want to remove from both lists the imaginary numbers that do not have a conjugate.

For example, the following lists `x = [3, 4, 2, 7, 4]` and `y = [2, -1, 0, 6, 1]` represent the numbers :

```
3 + 2j    <- no conjugate (to remove)
4 - 1j    <- conjugate (to keep)
2 + 0j    <- real (to keep)
4 + 1j    <- conjugate (to keep)
7 + 6j    <- no conjugate (to remove)
```

The expected result is the following :

```
new_x = [4, 2, 4]
new_y = [-1, 0, 1]
```

Any idea how i can achieve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will find complex conjugates from lists `x` and `y`:

```
x = [3, 4, 2, 7, 4]
y = [2, -1, 0, 6, 1]

tmp = {}
for r, i in zip(x, y):
    tmp.setdefault(i, set()).add(r)

x_out, y_out = [], []
for r, i in zip(x, y):
    if i==0 or r in tmp.get(-i, []):
        x_out.append(r)
        y_out.append(i)

print(x_out)
print(y_out)
```

Prints:

```
[4, 2, 4]
[-1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift answer, this works very well !